# Faça um algoritmo que retorne o maior valor de um array de números

Tags: javascript

Faça um algoritmo que retorne o maior valor de um array de números.
tem que retorna os negativos e se houver um array vazio tem que retornar 0

### Exemplo

```js
maxValue([10, 40, 30, 20, 50]) // 50
maxValue([10]) // 10
maxValue([30, 2, 1, -8]) // 30
maxValue([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, ]) // 10
maxValue([-1, -5 -10])// -1
maxValue([])// 0

e feito um teste automatizado
```

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?cb=1

Answer (score 1):

Lembre-se que o stackoverflow não é uma plataforma para resolver os seus problemas, apenas o fiz agora pois é algo simples o sufeciente e que consegue encontrar em qualquer lugar na net.
Poste sempre a sua tentativa e explique o que tentou fazer. Não vai melhorar tendo as soluções sem perceber o que fez de errado.

```
//Definir o vetor onde se quer encontrar o maior valor
var maxValue = [30, 2, 1, -8];

//Definir o primeiro maior valor como o primeiro numero do array
var maior= maxValue[0];

//Iterar o vetor
for (var i = 0; i < maxValue.length; i++) {

//Se o numero que tinha definido antes como o maior for menor que o numero do array onde estou, substituir o maior por esse numero do array
    if (maior< maxValue[i] ) {
        maior = maxValue[i];
    }
}

console.log(maior);
```

É um simples *for loop* para iterar sobre todos os elementos do *array* e verificar cada um para ver se é maior ou não do que o valor atual que temos guardado como maior.